# How to find the relative minimums of a vector (not the minimum value)

Tags: matlab, octave

Let's suposse I have a vector of values whose representation is the following one:

[image]

The vector of data has 2000 elements and as you see, there is another vector with degrees between -180º and 180º. I'd like to find the indices of each minimum peak, but I don't know how to implement the algorithm.

In other cases, I set a threshold value (for example -75dBm) and considered a minimum any value under -75dBm, but in this case, there are peaks above -70dBm and I can't increase the threshold value since my measurements will be wrong.

I hope someone can help me. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Use a kalman/lowpass filter (since your data look noisy) then use the built-in function `islocalmin`.

Comment: I have Matlab 2015 and the function `islocalmin` seems not to be implemented

Comment: so you can use in a same way `idy = findpeaks(-filtered_y)`

Comment: When I filter the data some of the minimums are so light that the `findpeaks` function doesn't find them

Comment: two choices: 1) improve your filter 2) do not apply a filter and detect all the realtive minima (but you will get a looooot of minima).

Comment: I have come up with the idea of finding the peaks of the peaks I found

Comment: @obchardon You can use the additional outputs of `findpeaks` to get the peak height and width, and remove the ones which are too small. Use `findpeaks` on the unfiltered signal, remove surplus peaks below your threshold height.

Comment: @Wolfie, Ho right forgot about that, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

For data like this, your best bet is to smooth it and then use findpeaks.

For an example

```
%% parameters to adjsut
%smoothing window length
smthwin=50;
%minimum peak prominence
mpp=0.01;

%% create some test data
x=(1:1000)/1000;
y=sin(3*x-0.5).*sin(5*x).*sin(9*x-0.1).*sin(15*x-0.3)+rand(size(x))/10;

%% smooth and findpeaks
%smooth it
%here I use a median filter, but smooth() is a great function too with lots of options 
ysmth=medfilt1(y,smthwin);

%use findpeaks on -y to find local minima
[pks,pks_loc]=findpeaks(-ysmth,'MinPeakProminence',mpp);
%the location of the local minima is 
mins=x(pks_loc);

%%plot to check
figure
plot(x,y)
hold on
plot(mins,-pks,'o','LineWidth',2)
```

Comment: I don't think a blanket suggestion to smooth the data is best practise... your peaks might not align to the peaks in the original data. You're better off using the additional outputs of `findpeaks` and limiting your identified peaks on a height and/or width threshold, as I [already commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54924126/how-to-find-the-relative-minimums-of-a-vector-not-the-minimum-value?noredirect=1#comment96618324_54924126) on the question, or using `mpp` as you already have.